# Xcode: How do I move an object from one viewControllers view to another viewControllers view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, object, view

I'm writing an iPhone app in Xcode.

I want to create an object of the type UIButton (NewButton) in one viewcontrollers view (viewController1) and than I want to move it to another viewControllers view (viewController2).

Any suggestions on how I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just so you know I already knows how to create the object, it's just the moving part that is troubling me :)

Comment: Are you talking about a graphical animation? or just passing the object so that the second vc knows about its state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to pass the object which depend on the situation.
The most common ways to do that are either delegates or notifications.
An example of delegates:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

An example of notifications:
http://www.hivestudio.cat/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=54:technical-note-communicate-using-nsnotificationcenter&catid=35:technical-note-category&Itemid=76

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off creating 2 separate (but identical looking and/or acting) UIButtons, and put one button in each view, rather than trying to manage safely swapping a button view between 2 different view and controller stacks.

Comment: unfortunately that won't work for my purpose... but think I've found a way to make it work